# Even team distribution

Tags: math, logic

I have **60 students** that need be divided into **12 teams**. Teams should be distributed evenly by **gender** and **nationality**.

What's an effective approach to accomplish this?

I've tried a list of example data with 9 students that should be divided into 3 teams:

```
A: Adam, Male, Sweden
B: Bob, Male, Norway
C: Charlie, Female, Denmark
D: David, Male, Denmark
E: Erica, Female, Sweden
F: Frida, Female, Norway
G: Gunnar, Male, Denmark
H: Hans, Male, Norway
I: Anna, Female, Sweden
```

I thought perhaps one way would be to first sort by nationality:

```
AEIBFHCDG
```

And then take n+3 to create evenly distributed team by nationality:

```
ABC
EFD
IHG
```

Then look diagonally for the second iteration:

```
AFG
BDI
CEH
```

But doesn't really go further than that. Any ideas on what approach I should use for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first decide what is more important the distribution of gender or nationality with a team. If you think gender is more important do the following with Python:

```
# todo: read in input
number_of_teams = 12
sorted_students = sorted(input) # todo: use your own comparator
team_list = [[] for _ in xrange(number_of_teams)] # create a list of 12 teams
# a team is modelled as a list 
for i, student in enumerate(sorted_students):
    team_list[i % number_of_teams].append(student)
```